# highchart map create marker by click and get lat long coordinates

Tags: vector, highcharts

I recently started using the map plugin. And Faced the problem of creating markers on click and displaying latitude and longitude on world map. Maybe someone has an example of how to implement this. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `click` event for a chart and series, calculate lat and lon values and add new point to the `mappoint` series.

```
Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
    chart: {
        map: 'custom/world-continents',
        events: {
            click: function(e) {
                const latlon = this.fromPointToLatLon({
                    x: e.xAxis[0].value,
                    y: e.yAxis[0].value
                });

                this.series[1].addPoint(latlon);
            }
        }
    },

    plotOptions: {
        map: {
            events: {
                click: function(e) {
                    const {
                        chart,
                        xAxis,
                        yAxis
                    } = this;

                    const latlon = chart.fromPointToLatLon({
                        x: xAxis.toValue(e.x),
                        y: yAxis.toValue(e.y)
                    });

                    chart.series[1].addPoint(latlon);
                }
            }
        }
    },
    ...
    series: [{
        ...
    }, {
        type: 'mappoint',
        colorAxis: null,
        enableMouseTracking: false,
        color: 'red',
        dataLabels: {
            allowOverlap: true,
            formatter: function() {
                const {
                    lat,
                    lon
                } = this.point;

                return 'Lat: ' + (lat.toFixed(2)) + '<br>Lon: ' + (lon.toFixed(2))
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6p1bv0jn/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#transformToLatLon

https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/chart.events.click

https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/plotOptions.map.events.click